# Is there a searchable food catalog of USDA Organic products?

Tags: organic

Is there a website that I can search for all products certified by USDA [with one of the 4 organic labels](https://www.ams.usda.gov/sites/default/files/media/Labeling%20Organic%20Products%20Fact%20Sheet.pdf):

- 100% Organic
- Organic
- Made with Organic
- Some Organic ingredients

For example, how can I found a list of brands sell sugar that is labelled "100% organic" by USDA?

Answer (score 2):

The [USDA Organic Integrity Database](https://organic.ams.usda.gov/integrity/) people search for Organic certifications and the foods lists the foods they were certified for.

https://apps.ams.usda.gov/Integrity/

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the [IFPS PLU Search page](http://www.ifpsglobal.com/Identification/PLU-Codes/PLU-codes-Search) for that. Instead of entering a code to search, leave all the fields blank and click on "Submit." When the first page of the list appears, click on the "Export" button and choose between .xlsx, .xls or .csv for your desired list format.

It may be possible to get a list of just the organic produce by specifying that segment of PLU codes (the ones that start with 9), but I'm not sure. I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up foods by product name in the [USDA Food Composition Databases](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search), and if "organic" is in the name, it is USDA organic.

Comment: Note that this is not a complete list (I believe it only covers manufacturered products? or possibly only things with nutrition labels?), while the link you fixed (thank you!) in Raghu Dodda's answer appears to be the actual full USDA organic database.